# Celery not carrying out a scheduled, repeating, task

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Django to set up a web-server that monitors prices on a stock. I therefore want a task (updating the price) to occur every 5 seconds, with a console log telling me about the update. Why won't Celery write to console as asked?

My file structure:

```
├── Project
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── Application
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   |── tasks.py
│   |── tests.py
│   |── views.py
```

My Celery setup in settings.py:

```
# Celery
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600

# Celery repeating tasks
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'notify-every-10-seconds': {
         'task': 'Main.tasks.update',
         'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
    },
}
```

And the task itself:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task
from .models import NasdaqShare


@shared_task
def update():
    print('Updated!')
```

When running the celery worker network, using the Django database, it appears to even list Application.tasks.update as a task to run.

Why am I not seeing anything being printed to console then?

If you'd like any more information, let me know.

Comment: Celery writes to the console where you run it and not to the console/stdout from where you send the message off. How do you run celery in production? As its own daemonized process using celeryd, with supervisor, ... You will find the output in the related logfiles. If you could provide some more information about your setup. You might also need to set the appropriate loglevel and run celery -l info.

Comment: are you running an instance of celery in beat mode? If not, those scheduled tasks will never get picked up.

Comment: Falk, I'm running Celery from a terminal in my IDE, where it displays a banner and a collection of information. Would the message appear in the same terminal?

Comment: Luke, I don't know if I'm running in beat mode, I'm using the command 'celery -A Project worker -l info'. Is that correct?

Comment: For scheduled tasks you need celery beat and a message queue such as RabbitMQ, and to make sure they all communicate with each other and with the celery backend properly.  See the documentation linked in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the [celery beat scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler), e.g. `celery -A Project beat`